# How do correct the funtion to run prepared statements in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've rewritten the connection to database from mysqli to PDO. My connection works with prepared statements. My class PDO look like that:

```
  <?php

define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASS', 'xxx');
define('DB_CHAR', 'xxx');

class DBController
{
    protected static $instance;
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $opt  = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
        );
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);

    }

    // a classical static method to make it universally available
    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    // a proxy to native PDO methods
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->pdo, $method), $args);
    }

    // a helper function to run prepared statements smoothly
    public function run($sql, $args = [])
    {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
    function insert($query) {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }

    function update($query) {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

The connection to database with new class PDO works clearly. But, when I want to login as an user I've got an 'Invalid Login'. However, login and password has been correct.

My class Auth look like that:

```
       <?php
require "DBController.class.php";

class Auth {

    protected $db;

    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = DBController::instance();
    }

        function getMemberByUsername($username)
    {
        $this->data = $this->db->run("Select * from `members` where `member_name` = ?", array($username))->fetchAll(0);
    }


    function getTokenByUsername($username,$expired)
    {
        $this->data = $this->db->run("Select * from `tbl_token_auth` where `username` = ? and `is_expired` = ?", [$username, $expired])->fetchAll();
    }

    function markAsExpired($tokenId)
    {
        $expired = 1;
        $this->data = $this->db->run("UPDATE `tbl_token_auth` SET `is_expired` = ? WHERE id = ?", [$expired, $tokenId])->fetchAll();
    }

    function insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date)
    {
        $this->data = $this->db->run("INSERT INTO `tbl_token_auth` (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) values (?, ?, ?,?)", [$username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date])->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

Below the code, which works with function getMemberByUsername

```
if (! empty($_POST["login"])) {
$isAuthenticated = false;

$username = $_POST["member_name"];
$password = $_POST["member_password"];

$user = $auth->getMemberByUsername($username);
if (password_verify($password, $user[0]["member_password"])) {
    $isAuthenticated = true;
}
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Basically, we have no idea why some code we cannot see is writing you "invalid login" and whether this message has any connection to your PDO functions.

Comment: From what I can tell there is nothing wrong with some random code parts you posted in your question.

Comment: I've  added the code, which workes with function getMemberByUsername

Comment: Your mysqli function returns array of rows while PDO function returns a single row. Do not treat it as an array

Comment: Please give me a hand - in what part of the code is mistake.

Comment: At least that [0] part is unnecessary. But there could be other issues. you should really enable PHP error reporting, it will always give you a clue

Comment: Could you post the full class here, please? You can remove the old MySQLi class, so it is less confusing.

Comment: I've left only PDO code.